# Cannot get control back from web view to react native app in OAuth flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, react-native, appauth

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth 2 signin using FormidableLab's [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) library in my react native android application as shown below:

```
  googleLoginPressed = async () => {
    const config = {
      serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth', tokenEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth', 
      },
      clientId: app_params.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, redirectUrl: 'https://<my_domain>/oauth/google',
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'], additionalParameters: { 'response-type': 'code' },
    };
    try {
      const result = await authorize(config);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

This invokes a web view with Google's signin page and I could successfully authenticate myself. Google then correctly redirects to my oauth callback endpoint and populates the oauth `code` in the redirect url like it should. At this point, I expect `react-native-app-auth` to get the control back from the webview to application. Instead, the web view stays open at the redirect url page.

I have added necessary website association configuration under `AndroidManifest.xml` and the following code under `MainActivity.java` to check for getting the control back to application from the redirect url:

```
  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { // this is not getting hit
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Uri appLinkData = intent.getData();

    if (appLinkData != null) {
      bar = appLinkData.getPath();
    }
  }
```

*What I tried so far*

- I ensured my app can open `Universal links`. So [website association](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#web-assoc) must be working fine.
- Also tried replicating the entire setup on iOS. Same result. The webview shows Google correctly redirecting to oauth endpoint but app fails to get control back.

How do I get control back from oauth web view to my react-native code?

Comment: We are also facing same issue.. We are getting success for Oauth request but it does not return the control back to app. Do you have any suggestion? We have react native app. it is working fine for Android but not for IOS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Claimed HTTPS Schemes, which is the most recommended security option for mobile apps, you are likely to also need an interstitial page after login, that triggers the Universal Link.

My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/) has further info and a code sample you can run, though it uses plain Kotlin rather than React Native.